# Will adding data at the end of a pdf corrupt it?

Tags: json, pdf, metadata

I want to store a large amount of metadata in a pdf (roughly 20+kb of plaintext json). I am experimenting with appending it to a pdf after the last %%EOF and it works in all the viewers I have tried.

Is there any reason that appending text in that way could cause the pdf to not open in a viewer, be flagged as corrupt/malicious, or any other negative effects?

Comment: Allright, I was afraid of that. I don't know of any PHP libraries that can do that. I think that feature is just going to have to be done differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

First of all, a viewer has to start reading a PDF file from the end. You're forcing it to consume a large amount of useless data in order to find the required %%EOF signature that tells it where all of the other elements in the file are. I would expect a PDF/A checker for example to flag such a file as non-conforming.

Secondly, the PDF specification says: "The last line of the file shall contain only the end-of-file marker, %%EOF", which means you're breaking the specification by doing what you do.

You can either store the information in a stream inside the PDF (plaintext or ZIP compressed) or you can embed it as a file (a file attachment) which allows it to be extracted more easily as there are certainly tools that can show and work with embedded files. Both would make more sense to me. You could also look at storing this information inside the XMP metadata in the PDF file (the normal way to store metadata in PDF documents), but that might be difficult / ill-advised given the size of the data you want to embed.

Comment: Exactly. Furthermore, while pure PDF viewers might be quite forgiving, pdf processing software might not be. And any processing step (e.g. applying an integrated digital signature) might either totally discard the added data or move it into the interior of the file.